# MySQL - Exclude rows from Select based on duplication of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to narrow results of an existing complex query based on conditional matches on multiple columns within the returned data set. I'll attempt to simplify the data as much as possible here.

Assume that the following table structure represents the data that my existing complex query has already selected (here ordered by `date`):

```
+----+-----------+------+------------+
| id | remote_id | type | date       |
+----+-----------+------+------------+
|  1 |         1 | A    | 2011-01-01 |
|  3 |         1 | A    | 2011-01-07 |
|  5 |         1 | B    | 2011-01-07 |
|  4 |         1 | A    | 2011-05-01 |
+----+-----------+------+------------+
```

I need to select from that data set based on the following criteria:

- If the pairing of `remote_id` and `type` is unique to the set, return the row always
- If the pairing of `remote_id` and `type` is **not** unique to the set, take the following action:

  - Of the sets of rows for which the pairing of `remote_id` and `type` are not unique, return *only* the single row for which `date` is *greatest* and still *less than or equal to* now.

So, if today is `2011-01-10`, I'd like the data set returned to be:

```
+----+-----------+------+------------+
| id | remote_id | type | date       |
+----+-----------+------+------------+
|  3 |         1 | A    | 2011-01-07 |
|  5 |         1 | B    | 2011-01-07 |
+----+-----------+------+------------+
```

For some reason I'm having no luck wrapping my head around this one. I suspect the answer lies in good application of `group by`, but I just can't grasp it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You say out of the non-unique rows, you want to return the greatest date, but still <= now. The date you pulled for type A is greater than the date you specified for 'today'.

Comment: My mistake! I forgot it is 2011 ;) Corrected OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/* Rows with exactly one date - always return regardless of when date occurs */
SELECT id, remote_id, type, date
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY remote_id, type
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
UNION
/* Rows with more than one date - Return Max date <= NOW */
SELECT yt.id, yt.remote_id, yt.type, yt.date
    FROM YourTable yt
        INNER JOIN (SELECT remote_id, type, max(date) as maxdate
                        FROM YourTable
                        WHERE date <= DATE(NOW())
                        GROUP BY remote_id, type
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) sq
             ON yt.remote_id = sq.remote_id
                 AND yt.type = sq.type
                 AND yt.date = sq.maxdate
```

Comment: Unfortunately the second part of the query returns results which are undefined: The resulting ID of the row (happens to be in this case) 1, when no such row actually exists. The actual row id for the data shown would be 3 in this example. I need to maintain id association, which is what makes this so difficult.

Comment: @Carson C.: I've modified my answer. Does this version work better?

Comment: I made some changes to my test data to include single future dates as well as null dates. Your code works for all cases. The only change I had to make was to add `or date is null` to the where clause of the second half of the union. Otherwise multiple row sets with some null dates would return nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The group by clause groups all rows that have identical values of one or more columns together and returns one row in the result set for them.  If you use aggregate functions (min, max, sum, avg etc.) that will be applied for each "group".

```
SELECT id, remote_id, type, max(date) 
FROM blah 
GROUP BY remote_id, date;
```

I'm not whore where today's date comes in, but assumed that was part of the complex query that you didn't describe and I assume isn't directly relevant to your question here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM table a INNER JOIN 
             (
                select remote_id, type, MAX(date) date, COUNT(1) cnt from table
                 group by remote_id, type
             ) b
 WHERE a.remote_id = b.remote_id, 
                 AND a.type = b.type
                 AND a.date = b.date
                 AND ( (b.cnt = 1) OR (b.cnt>1 AND b.date <= DATE(NOW())))
```

Comment: Perfect! This performs exactly as hoped, by adding `where date <= date(now())` to the nested select. Thank you!

Comment: @Carson C.: What would happen in the case where you have a single row with a date in the future? My understanding is that you'd want that row returned and I believe this version (with your added where on the subquery) would not return that row.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: You make an excellent point. I need to explore this further.

Comment: @Carson C.: Please take another look at [my modified answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629097/mysql-exclude-rows-from-select-based-on-duplication-of-two-columns/4629172#4629172).

Comment: Updated the query to address the gap identified by Joe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select id, remote_id, type, MAX(date) from table
group by remote_id, type
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Carson! You could try using the "distinct" keyword on those two fields, and in a union you can use Count() along with group by and some operators to pull non-unique (greatest and less-than today) records!